# Why does using ksort() in a return context fail, but other standard functions work

Tags: php, arrays, ksort

When using PHP's `ksort()` function in a return context like so,

```
function test() {
    $items = array(
        126 => 'apple',
        41 => 'pear',
        80 => 'mango'
    );

    return ksort($items);
}

$result = test();
var_dump($result); // bool(true)
```

The result that I get is `bool(true)` when var_dumped.

On the other hand, when using ksort like it's used in the PHP documentation, it works.

```
function test() {
    $items = array(
        126 => 'apple',
        41 => 'pear',
        80 => 'mango'
    );

    ksort($items)
    return $items;
}

$result = test();
var_dump($result); // properly ordered array
```

I'm able to use other PHP functions in a return context, so my question is why doesn't ksort work in the first example, and why does it return true?

Answer (score 4):

Because `ksort()` changes the original Array, yet returns a boolean value. In your second example you're returning the Array, the first example just returns the return value of `ksort()`.

Please read the documentation:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php

Comment: Ah yes I just checked the PHP docs again and I missed that it returns a boolean. I thought that a variable had to be passed by reference for something like that to work. Thanks a lot!